# Set read and write only permission (with no delete!) vsFTPd

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

Today at work my boss, give me order: in internal company's FTP, where we have backups, users can upload and download files, but they can't delete them. I have to do this in vsFTPd's config. He told me, he did it once, but he forgot how do that.
Is it possible? Anyone can help me or take me even tips, how to reach it.

Comment: Are the users logging in or are they anonymous?

Comment: No. as user. :) 
I have a solution: http://serverfault.com/a/374697/253490
Anyway thank you for your interest.

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting my answer (which is just a copy of the serverfault answer) so that other users on AskUbuntu can easily find the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so you would simply have to remove the following from the config:

```
# Disable delete commands
cmds_denied=DELE,RMD
```

Where `DELE` is delete file permission and `RMD` is remove directory permission.

Taken from [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/374697/253490) as suggested in the comments by @Pretenderus.